# Downsampling Wav audio files in datasets

Tags: audio, dataset, speech-recognition, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I have taken the LJ Speech dataset from Hugging Face for Automatic Speech Recognition Training.
Link to dataset: https://huggingface.co/datasets/lj_speech
The sampling rate of the audio is 22050 Hz.
I want to convert it into **16000 Hz** for the whole dataset.

code and output
`lj_data['audio'][0]`

output
[screenshot of audio file description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eaNY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out the answer.
Hugging face has some amazing functions, which can resample the file.

```
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric, Audio

#loading data
data = load_dataset("lj_speech")


#resampling training data from 22050Hz to 16000Hz
data['train'] = data['train'].cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=16_000))
```

To see documentation: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/audio_process.html

Results:

Before Resampling
[Before Resampling- 22050Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1sN2.png)

After Resampling:
[After Resampling - 16000Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPZxo.png)